# Primitive and Prime Cycles in graph

Tags: graph

I am reading an article. It defines types of graph cycles as primitive and prime cycles. what means by primitive cycles in a graph and prime cycles in a graph....?

Comment: which article is it?

Comment: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel7/5962385/6494635/06478830.pdf this s the artile, a research paper on backtrackless walks on a graph

Comment: Funny I just read that paper too. From the paper: A cycle is primitive if it is not the r-multiple of some other cycle b for r≥2....A prime cycle is the equivalence class of primitive cycles, which have no backtracking or tail, written as [c]. What is your interest in that topic?

Comment: Actullay I am studying graph kernels. what means by equivalence class of primitive cycles..?

Comment: interesting. see my edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the paper:

*A cycle **c** is primitive, if it is not the **r**-multiple of some other cycle **b** for **r≥2**.*

...

*Two cycles **c1=(e1,e2,...e_n)** and **c2=(f1,f2,...f_n)** are equivalent if there is a fixed **a** such that **e_i=f_(i+a)**.* [All equivalent cycles represent the equivalence class **[c]**.]

...

*A prime cycle is the equivalence class of primitive cycles, which
have no backtracking or tail, written as **[c]**.*